# Is there a standard function to determine if a String is a valid variable/funciton name in Kotlin/Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

In Kotlin/Java, is there a standard function to determine if a String is a valid variable/function name without having to wrap it in back-ticks?
As in

```
functionIAmLookingFor("do-something") shouldBe false
functionIAmLookingFor("doSomething") shouldBe true
```

Edit: I do not want to enclose everything in backticks.

The reason why we need this: we have a tool that serializes instances into compilable Kotlin. And we have encountered the following edge case:

```
enum class AssetType { TRANSFERRABLE, `NON-TRANSFERRABLE` }
```

so as we reflect an instance with a field `NON-TRANSFERRABLE`, we need to wrap it in back-ticks:

```
val actual = MyAsset( type = `NON-TRANSFERRABLE`
```

This is why I'm asking this. Currently we are just saying in `README` that we do not support any names that require back-ticks at this time.

Comment: That is a rather unusual requirement. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by saying "do-something" is not a valid function name? It is a valid name, only not standard / recommended one.

Comment: Usually your text editor or your ide would give you a waning if you use a keyword as a variable or function name.

Comment: Everything can be a function or variable name in kotlin, because even if there is a reserved keyword in there, you could “escape” it with two backticks, except for _, __, ___.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it manually:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierPart(char)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isJavaIdentifierStart(char)

Something like this:

```
boolean isJavaIdentifier(String s) {
  if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) return false;
  if (!Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(s.charAt(0)) {
    return false;
  }
  for (int i = 1, n = s.length(); i < n; ++i) {
    if (!Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(s.charAt(i)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true; 
}
```

I don't know for Kotlin, but I don't think there is much difference using
770grappenmaker answer as reference.

Comment: Needless to say the Kotlin language (that I don't know) may have its own subset of identifier start.

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at the kotlin compiler lexer. It has some predefined variables, here is an excerpt:

```
LETTER = [:letter:]|_
IDENTIFIER_PART=[:digit:]|{LETTER}
PLAIN_IDENTIFIER={LETTER} {IDENTIFIER_PART}*
ESCAPED_IDENTIFIER = `[^`\n]+`
IDENTIFIER = {PLAIN_IDENTIFIER}|{ESCAPED_IDENTIFIER}
FIELD_IDENTIFIER = \${IDENTIFIER}
```

Source: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/psi/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/lexer/Kotlin.flex

These seem to be some kind of regexes, you could combine them to your needs and just match on them. As far as I can tell, this is how the compiler validates identifier names.

Edit: of course, this is code of the lexer, which means that if it finds any other token, it is invalid. All tokens and how to identify them are defined in that file and in the KtTokens file. You could use this information as a reference to find illegal tokens. For java, use the answer of NoDataFound.